# MariaDB Async Await Always Returns undefined | NodeJS

Tags: node.js, async-await, mariadb

In trying to get tokens from a MariaDB database from withing a NodeJS server utilizing the provided npm connector package. The logging inside my getter function (below) outputs the correct entries and they should then be returned up the stack.

```js
async function getDBToken(uuid) {
  let conn;
  try {
      conn = await pool.getConnection();
      const rows = await conn.query(`SELECT * FROM Tokens WHERE uuid='${uuid}'`);
      console.log(rows)
      return rows;
  } catch (err) {
      throw err;
  } finally {
      if (conn) return conn.end();
  }
}
```

However, the caller (an API endpoint, below) logs `undefined` (and uses it for its logic) despite the earlier verification that it has the correct value.

```js
  app.post("/loggedin/:timestamp", async (req, res) => {
    // ...
    const token = await getDBToken(req.body.uuid)
    console.log(token);
    // ...
```

I have verified that this appears to be an issue (or mistake on my part) with the query function in MariaDB as replacing `conn.query` with any simple async function like `const test = async () => { return "test" }` does not have this issue.

Comment: For starters you have a SQL injection security issue.

Comment: I'm aware of that, I am developing a proof of concept on a relatively short time scale and have had more pressing concerns than security. I'm planning on thinking about security more once I have completed the major features

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue stems from the fact that you return from the function twice. This is problably the only case where this is even a possibility, but when running this code:

```js
function foo() {

  try {
    return 1;
  } finally {
    return 2;
  }
}

console.log(foo());
```

You will get `2`. I was surprised to learn this.

So a corrected version of your code would look like this:

```js
async function getDBToken(uuid) {
  let conn;
  try {
      conn = await pool.getConnection();
      return conn.query('SELECT * FROM Tokens WHERE uuid=?', uuid);
  } finally {
      if (conn) conn.end();
  }
}
```

I took out the unneeded catch block, as it doesn't do anything. Furthermore, if your code only executes this 1 query there's also not really a point to obtaining a connection and releasing it, you can just run:

```js
function getDBToken(uuid) {
  return pool.query('SELECT * FROM Tokens WHERE uuid=?', uuid);
}
```

Or:

```js
const getDBToken = 
  uuid => pool.query('SELECT * FROM Tokens WHERE uuid=?', uuid);
```

Comment: Adding +1, because solution even indicate to pass parameter instead of creating SQL that can lead to injection